# Bootstrap 3 можно ли использовать несколько .container на странице

Tags: css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени суток, подскажите, при верстке на `bootstrap 3` , нормально ли использовать 4-5 `.container` и `.container-fluid`, на одной странице, или лучше воздержаться?

В интернете везде в примерах вся страница находиться в `container`, а внутри `row-ы`.

Но как быть с динамическими сайтами, а не с детскими страничками, иногда на странице хочется впихнуть 10-15 модулей , делать их все `row-ами` - не особо хочется, так как некоторым хочется дать `fluid` - например слайд шоу или баннеры, а некоторым категорически нет, только контейнер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`continer` и `container-fluid` это грубо говоря обычные блоки, которые можно разбить на сетку таблицы. Соответсвенно как и использование несколько `div` на одной странице вполне нормально, так и тут. Но у этих классов есть уже свои определенные стили которые задают их поведение. Так например стили для того что-бы `container-fluid` растягивался на всю страницу или стили для разбития контейнера на сетку. Потому дабы избежать разных казусов, лучше их не делать многоуговневыми. Тобишь внутри контейнера лучше делать разметку с помощью строк и столбцов.

Answer (score 2):

Это совершенно нормально, никаких побочных эффектов у контейнера нет. Не стоит, разве что, вкладывать их друг в друга (но это и незачем делать).

Comment: Спасибо, а чем вы можете мотивировать свой ответ ?

Comment: @Дмитрий, посмотрите в css-файле какие стили добавляет контейнер и все поймете сами.

Comment: Не знаю, чем это можно мотивировать, кроме прикладывания стилей, которые прописываются контейнеру...